# Ajax Calendar always visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Is it possible to have an ajax calendar inside a div and make it be always visible,like asp:calendar? and highlight today's date and add some task to the calendar for different dates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: specify what calendar you are using

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing an `asp:calendar` on a simple page, and picking apart the html that it generates until you get the effect that you are after.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options I see.

1. Put the ASP:Calendar inside an Update Panel to mimic the AJAX effect. ***CHEAPEST AND EASIEST!***
2. Write some JQUERY code that will look for the div on client side that has the visibility hidden and make it visible. See the visibility:hidden and display:none...that's what need to be changed. Then you will also have to write something else that will keep on setting this to display for each click and other event so that it is always displayed. ***THIS IS NOT A GOOD SOLUTION!***

   div id="ctl00_MainContent_ReportControl_CalendarExtender2_container" class="ajax__calendar" style="position: absolute; left: 766px; top: 775px; z-index: 1000; visibility: hidden; display: none;"
3. Use a 3rd party control like the Telerik RadCalendar.